# How to change product image window in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, responsiveness

I am trying to place an image of 400x400 as my product image. But this image appears stretched and blurred. The reason I think is that the default window size of product image is 562x562.On hovering over the image,the actual resolution of the image i.e. 400x400 is visible. So is there any way to change the dimension of window in woocommerce??
Here is the link http://mytalaash.com/product/image-2-2/

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Change the image size in the WooCommerce settings.